# Python Indentation Issue

Tags: python, indentation

```
groceries = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = { "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = { "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

# Write your code below!
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0 
    for item in food:
        total = total + prices[item]
        return total
```

Why do I get wrong results with the above code, and correct results with the code below:

```
# Write your code below!
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0 
    for item in food:
        total = total + prices[item]
    return total
```

Is the indentation difference the cause of the difference?

Comment: If you don't yet know that indentation matters in Python then you should start with [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).

Comment: also, also this does not quite relate, you can replace total=total+prices[item] with total+=prices[item]

Answer (score 3):

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation):

> Leading whitespace (spaces and tabs) at the beginning of a logical
>   line is used to compute the indentation level of the line, which in
>   turn is used to determine the grouping of statements.

So, indentation Matters a lot in Python.

Code 1:

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0 
    for item in food:
        total = total + prices[item]
        return total
```

As the `return` statement is inside the `for` loop, it actually returns from the function after just one iteration.

In-fact the above code is equivalent to :

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0                       # Consider food[0] is the first key.
    total = total + prices[food[0]] # just fetch the price of first item in food
    return total                    # add it to total and return total
```

Code 2:

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0 
    for item in food:
        total = total + prices[item]
    return total
```

Here `return` statement is not inside the for-loop block, so your function will iterate over the whole food iterable first and once the iteration is over `total` is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is the indentation. The `return` statement is executed in the first iteration.

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0 
    for item in food:
        total = total + prices[item]
    return total
```

In this code, you iterate over all the values and sum them up and then return the variable `total`.

Whereas, in this

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0 
    for item in food:
        total = total + prices[item]
        return total
```

You add only the first item to the `total` and return it, which is not the sum of all the values.

Answer (score 0):

of course the indentation made a difference, in :

```
for item in food:
    total = total + prices[item]
    return total
```

you return the total variable at first iteration of the for loop, whereas in :

```
for item in food:
    total = total + prices[item]
return total
```

you return the total **after** all the iterations have been made in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Yeah in Python Indentation does valued a lot!

It is a common mistake which new python programmers make.

The first one put returns in the loop and hence returns in the first loop then return and terminate the loop right away.

The second one put returns outside of the loop so only return once when the for loop is finished and the sum of cost is done calculation.

Indentation does make a great difference in Python, unlike in C++ or JAVA.

Comment: No! `return` is executed only once, not in every loop. A function stops it's execution when it encounters a `return` statement for the first time and returns a  value. That's why the first code ends pre-maturely.